# How can I tell if a smart contract on RSK is an NFT?

Tags: solidity, nft, rsk

Given an address of a smart contract deployed to RSK, how can I tell if it is an NFT or not? Is there a "standard" way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is a definitive way to do this,
if the smart contracts implement well-known token standards for NFTs,
which in turn implement the well-known [EIP165 Standard Interface Definition](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165).

(1) The easiest way to do this is to simply look up the address on the RSK block explorer.

If the smart contract address is `0x814eb350813c993df32044f862b800f91e0aaaf0`, then go to
https://explorer.rsk.co/address/0x814eb350813c993df32044f862b800f91e0aaaf0

On this page, you will see a row for "Contract Interfaces",
and in the case of this smart contract,
displays `ERC165 ERC721 ERC721Enumerable ERC721Metadata`.
Since this contains `ERC721`, we know that it implements that token standard for non-fungible tokens.

(2) The more programmatic/ DIY way to do this is to use the function defined in the EIP165 standard, whose interface is copied below:

```
interface ERC165 {
    /// @notice Query if a contract implements an interface
    /// @param interfaceID The interface identifier, as specified in ERC-165
    /// @dev Interface identification is specified in ERC-165. This function
    ///  uses less than 30,000 gas.
    /// @return `true` if the contract implements `interfaceID` and
    ///  `interfaceID` is not 0xffffffff, `false` otherwise
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool);
}
```

Without going too much into the math of how this is calculated,
(read the EIP-165 standard for the full description/ explanation)
if invoking  `supportsInterface` returns `true`, then you know
that that this smart contracts (claims to) implement that particular interface.

- If you wish to test if a particular smart contract implements the
  ["Non-Fungible Token Standard"](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721):

  - call `supportsInterface(0x80ac58cd)`
- If you wish to test if a particular smart contract implements the
  ["Multi Token Standard"](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155),
  which is presently the 2nd most popular NFT standard:

  - call `supportsInterface(0xd9b67a26)`

(Note that while both of the above values are stated in their respective standards,
you may also wish to calculate them yourself, and the EIP-165 standard includes  section on how to do this.)